# Add member variable to class in the shared library, will not break binary compatibility?

Tags: c++, qt, class, binary-compatibility

I had wanted to find an example to express my understanding of binary compatibility, but blown it. I want to change the layout of members of class in the DLL by add members to class at the beginning or in the middle, and expect that the variable cannot be accessed correctly
or accessing the variable will generate crash.However, everything goes well. I find, no matter how I add member variable to any position of class，there are no crash and not breaking binary compatibility. My code as following:

```
//untitled1_global.h
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(UNTITLED1_LIBRARY)
#  define UNTITLED1_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define UNTITLED1_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

```
//base.h
class UNTITLED1_EXPORT Base
{
public:
    Base();

    double getA();
    double getB();

private:
    int arr[100]; //Add later to update the DLL
    double a;
    double b;
};
```

```
//derived.h
#include "dpbase.h"
class UNTITLED1_EXPORT Derived :  public Base
{
public:
    Derived();
    void setC(double d);
    double getC();

private:
    char arrCh[100]; //Add later to update the DLL
    double c;
};
```

Below is the client code，`base.h`、`derived.h` included aren't same as in the DLL, one is annotated and one not. Implementation and declaration are separate in the DLL.I tried to access the variable directly and access the variable by funcation（such as annotated at the beginning of `main.cpp`）.

```
//main.cpp
#include "dpbase.h"
#include "dpbase2.h"
#include <QDebug>

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Base base;
    qDebug() << base.getA();
    qDebug() << base.getB();

    Derived base2;
    base2.setC(50);
    qDebug() << base2.getC();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Among them, class `Base`,`Derived` is exported from **dll**.
No matter how I add member variable to whether `Base` or `Derived`  anywhere，there are no crash and not breaking binary compatibility.

I am using qt.There is a
[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317106/why-new-virtual-function-will-not-break-binary-compatibility-per-phenomenon/49317998#comment111284327_49317998) here, but no help for me.

Furthermore, I delete all member var of class in the DLL, I still use nonexistent variable in the client by linking the DLL,assign value, get it...It seems that there is enough space reserved in the dynamic library to be redefined by the client, even if no member variable is defined.So strange!

My question is, why changing the layout of members of class in the DLL, will not break binary compatibility?And deleting all member var of class in the DLL but why the caller can still use members in the .h file?

Comment: The language lawyers will tell you that you shouldn't do this. Reality - adding member vars to **the end** of a class declaration usually works, provided you are passing the class around via pointer. The calling code expecting the old implementation gets the same expected layout. However, the moment the calling code copies the class instance, all bets are off.**  And there's plenty of other corner cases with multiple/nested inheritance where this can break.  Basically, if it works, it works. But when you add another variable tomorrow, it might break.  End of story.

Comment: What you really want to do is either use the COM approach or something similar - a factory function exported out of the DLL that returns back a pointer to an interface declared with only pure virtual methods.  (e.g. declare an interface called `IDPBase` that only has pure virtual methods, and export a function that returns instances of this class).

Comment: @selbie I know add member var will break binary compatibility, and do a test for verification.I add member var to any position of a class , not just the end.What confuse me was that no crash and program run well.

Comment: If you've added a variable to the middle of the class, it might still work, but you've added a lot more risk.  If the calling code is inheriting from your class and adding its own members, it's going to depend on the layout of the members to be the same. Just calling methods that linked from your DLL, less of an issue.

Comment: @selbie I have changed the layout of the class in the `dpbase.h` file by adding `int n1_t`, and access var directly by "." .Stillly running normally.Furthermore, I delete all member var of class in the DLL, I still use nonexistent variable in the DLL,assign value, get it...It seems that there is enough space reserved in the dynamic library to be redefined by the client ,even if no member variable is defined.

Comment: I don't know what you want me to tell you.  You're doing risky stuff by adding variables into the middle of a class and still hoping to achieve binary compatibility.  It might work provider the caller is only accessing your class via pointer, only calling methods that aren't inlined in the header,  and not copying/inheriting. But if you want guaranteed binary compatibility between changes, you really should be exporting classes out of a DLL via factory functions and interfaces with only pure-virtual methods.

Comment: @selbie I know a lot about binary compatibility,I wanted write a demo for testing actually.I find adding/deleting member variable of class had no effect to binary compatibility seemingly.My question has been further updated and would you look it over.

Comment: Here i got the answer!https://forum.qt.io/topic/117553/add-member-variable-to-class-in-the-shared-library-will-not-break-binary-compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to understand how members are accessed.

Let's take

```
class UNTITLED1_EXPORT Base
{
public:
    Base();

    double getA();
    double getB();

private:
    double a;
    double b;
};
```

When you access `a` it is like doing `*(this + 0)`.
When you access `b` it is like doing `*(this + 8)` (assuming `double` is 8 bytes).

Then when you change you class like so:

```
class UNTITLED1_EXPORT Base
{
public:
    Base();

    double getA();
    double getB();

private:
    int arr[100];
    double a;
    double b;
};
```

When you access `a` it will do `*(this + 400)` and when you access `b` it will do `*(this + 408)`.

Now this may or may not be an issue. If you access `a` and `b` only through `getA()` and `getB()` and they are defined in a .cpp in your DLL, then you will update the definitions of the getters at the same time you update your class.

You could create some weird behaviors by makign the definition of the getters inline:

```
class UNTITLED1_EXPORT Base
{
public:
    Base();

    double getA() { return a; }
    double getB();

private:
    double a;
    double b;
};
```

In this case your .exe *might* have its own copy of `getA()` and `getB()`.
Meaning that aven after you update your DLL and add the `int arr[400]` your .exe will still try to access `*(this + 0)` which is now occupied by `arr`.

This is undefined behavior, but it will not make your program crash though, as you are accessing allocated memory.

If you do the opposite:

1. Compile your exe with the `arr`
2. Remove `arr`
3. Build the DLL
4. Run the .exe

Then you are more likely to have a crash. Because the exe will try to access `this + 400` while `Base` is only 16 bytes. But it is still not guaranteed to crash, for multiple reasons. For instance `this + 400` might be valid. But more importantly it depends on where you allocated the memory for `Base` from.
If you do `new Base` in your .exe then it will allocate 416 bytes even after your changed the DLL. But, if you do `new Base` in your DLL, it will allocate only 16 bytes.

---

Here is an exemple.

Here is the header for the .exe:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    double getA() const { return a; }
    double getB() const { return b; }
    static Base *create();
    void print();
private:
    double a;
    double b;
};
```

The header for the DLL

class Base
{
public:
Base();
double getA() const { return a; }
double getB() const;
static Base *create();
void print();
private:
int arr[400]
double a;
double b;
};

The code of the DLL:

```
Base::Base()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    a = 3.14;
    b = 1.42;
}

double Base::getB() const { return b; }

Base *Base::create()
{
    return new Base();
}

void Base::print()
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

And the code in my exe is:

```
Base *b = Base::create();

std::cout << b->getA() << std::endl;
std::cout << b->getB() << std::endl;
b->print();
```

Normally I should expect to have the output:

```
3.14
1.42
3.14
1.42
```

But in practice I have:

```
2.122e-314
1.42
3.14
1.42
```

The reason is that for the first line (`2.122e-314`) the exe is looking for `a` at address `this + 0`, but since this memory is now occupied by `arr` it is as we would have done: `std::cout << *((double *)arr)`.
The values for `b` are not affected because `b` is always read from the DLL as `getB()` is not inlined.

Now if I change `Base *b = Base::create();` by `Base *b = new B();` the program crashes because as the `new` is done from the .exe it will only allocate 16 bytes while `Base()` will access all its member variables across 416 bytes.

#### Note

For the purpose of this answer I did pointer arithmetic supposing the increment is always 1. In reality it is not.

So when I write `this + 8` it is to be understood in C++ as `reinterpret_cast<double *>(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this) + 8)`.

Comment: Is the statement "*(this + 8) (assuming double is 8 bytes)." true?.. I mean, it's a pointer arithmetic that depends on the size of the pointer.To move to the second variable You'd have to write '*(reinterpret_cast<double*>(this)+1)'.

Comment: @b00rt00s yes you are right. I did not want to enter into pointer arithmetics but strictly speaking it is: `*((double*)(((void*)this) + 8))`. It is also possible to do the arithmetics with double* like you did, but it won't work in the unlikely case that the double is not aligned properly.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure now, but I thought that pointer arithmetics doesn't work on void, because void has unknown size. Shouldn't that be a char?

Comment: @b00rt00s I just rechecked what the standards say and yes pointer arithmetics on void* are illegal. But it does work in some compilers in which case it does increment the address by 1.  So, indeed char* should be preferred.

Comment: I change Base `*b = Base::create();` by Base `*b = new B();` the program do not crash,.Btw, should change `getB()` to no inlining in the header for the DLL,otherwise can't link.I know the impact of binary compatibility on inlining before,could I think of it this way,**the binary compatibility problem of variable offset only when inlining**?

Comment: My second question, "deleting all member var of class in the DLL...", implies no inlining.

Comment: @Crawl.W I fixed the inlining of B in my answer. For the program crashing/not crashing, as I said in my answer there is not guarantee that the program will crash. You have undefined behavior, maybe it will crash, maybe it will work, maybe it will produce garbage output, who knows? The variable offset is not only an issue with inlining, but it is an easy way to demonstrate it.

Comment: @Crawl.W For the issue about removing all variables in the class. I do not understand what you expect. The .exe only uses functions of the class, not its variables. So you can remove the variables it won't change anything as long as you are calling non inline functions. And even if you made the variables public and used them in your exe, it will run because the exe just knows to access `this+offset` and you will have the same issues that I detailed about inline functions.

Comment: Removing all variables in the class that refers to the DLL and it requires no inline implementation Implicitly.

Comment: Setting the member variable to public, and the effect can be achieved directly through offset access, e.g. `Base base; base.a`, `Base *pBase = new Base; pBase->b`